Error getting sticky headers MaterialReactTable
I am trying to get a MaterialReactTable to render with sticky headers (and not the top/bottom bars) but am getting a weird error. When scrolling, only the last column stays fixed.

Relevant code snippet

const table = useMaterialReactTbale({
  …
  enableTableFooter: false,
  enableStickyHeader: true,
  enableTopToolbar: false,
  enableBottomToolbar: false,
  …
})  


return <MaterialReactTable table={table} />

Columns are defined as
[
  …
  {
    accessorKey: 'key',
    header: 'label',
    Cell: ({ cell, row }) => (),
    accessorFn: (originalValue) => originalValue.mutate
  }
]

Not all of them have Cell/accessorFn, and it doesn't matter which of the columns is last. The last one is always the only one that sticks.
I have tried adding enableStickyHeader and muiTableContainerProps (with max height, etc) to the <MaterialReactTable table={table} /> block, as suggested here but no change in sticky header rendering.
Any ideas what I am missing?
If there are possible css conflicts, what classes/defs/etc should I look for in our css files?
